# TFS Build workflow custom variable is empty after iniatilization

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, workflow-foundation-4, tfsbuild

I have created a custom variable `SourcesPath` in the outter most level of the workflow.
[image: Create Custom Variable SourcesPath]

Then I initialized it.
[image: Initializes SourcesPath]

I even see its value assigned when view log.

```
00:00
Initialize Sources Directory
Initial Property Values
Value = C:\Builds\3\Project Demo\Sources
Final Property Values
To = C:\Builds\3\Project Demo\Sources
Value = C:\Builds\3\Project Demo\Sources

00:00
Initialize SourcesPath For Later Use
Initial Property Values
Value = C:\Builds\3\Project Demo\Sources
Final Property Values
To = C:\Builds\3\Project Demo\Sources
Value = C:\Builds\3\Project Demo\Sources
```

Later it was used in an InvokeProcess activity.
[image: Later Use of SourcesPath]

But the variable appeared to be empty at runtime:

```
00:02
InvokeProcessSonar
Initial Property Values
Arguments = -X
EnvironmentVariables = 
FileName = c:\\Scan.bat
OutputEncoding = System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding
WorkingDirectory = \\Src\\Solution
c:\\Scan.bat
Final Property Values
Arguments =
EnvironmentVariables = 
FileName = c:\\Scan.bat
OutputEncoding = System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding
Result = 0
WorkingDirectory = \\Src\\Solution
Final Property Values
AgentSettings = Use agent where Name=* and Tags is empty; Max Wait Time: 04:00:00
AssociateChangesetsAndWorkItems = True
BuildNumberFormat = $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)
BuildSettings = Build $/ProjectDemo/Src/Solution/ProjectDemo.sln with default platform and configuration
CleanWorkspace = All
CreateLabel = True
DisableTests = False
DropBuild = False
GetVersion = 
MSBuildArguments = 
MSBuildPlatform = Auto
PerformTestImpactAnalysis = True
PrivateDropLocation = 
RunCodeAnalysis = AsConfigured
SourceAndSymbolServerSettings = Index Sources
TestSpecs = Run tests in assemblies matching **\*test*.dll
Verbosity = Diagnostic
 The directory name is invalid
```

Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run something at the end of the workflow, I would suggest placing your invoke process in the finaly which is part of the Try Compile, Test and Publish, this will be the last thing to fire in the agent scope, and your variable should still be in context

Comment: Thank you @JustTFS. I managed to move the InvokeProcess activity inside the Agent scope and use the built-in SourcesDirectory variable for the input of my activity. Everything works out now.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the name clashes with another variable in a nested scope.

I usually add a prefix (say an underscore `_`) to mark my variables and activities so it is both easy to spot what is standard and what is customized.

The root cause is supposing that variable values flow seamlessly through RunOnAgent, which is not. RunOnAgent scope is a completely isolated context from the rest of the workflow. TFS takes care of marshaling one way (toward the RunOnAgent scope) but not the other way round: only data in Build Information nodes. See [Returning Values From An AgentScope](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willbar/archive/2010/12/20/returning-values-from-an-agentscope.aspx).

In you case, your only chance is to move the InvokeProcess inside the RunOnAgent scope.

Comment: I already check the step-by-step execution log of the workflow. There is no name clashing found.

Comment: Sounds that it is not pushed to agent scope. Agent scope is assumed to share nothing with caller, so there are some hoopla to be aware.

Comment: I would move your declaration down to agent scope. which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: TFS server 2010. Visual Studio 2012. I cannot move my InvokeProcessSonar activity to Agent scope because it has to be executed at the very end of the workflow.

Comment: The InvokeProcess is at the same scope as the Assign?

Comment: so you're not running it on the build server? i.e. within the agent scope

Comment: @GiulioVian The Assign activity is inside the Agent scope, but the InvokeProcess is outside of the Agent scope.

Comment: @JustTFS the batch file is supposed to be executed on the build server, by the Agent's process.

Comment: Thank you @GiulioVian for your helpful diagnostics and suggestions.